# vertx 3 Setting external json configuration file

Tags: java, configuration, vert.x

I followed this tutorial from 2015 (outdated ?):
http://vertx.io/blog/vert-x-application-configuration/

I am using maven and vertx 3 with java 8, I tried passing an external json configuration to the fat jar using `java -jar ... -conf ...path/conf.json` the application starts but all config values are null.
It should either tell me the `-conf` option is unknown or that the config file was not found, but it just returns null.

```
  @Override
  public void start(final Future<Void> fut) {
    config().getString("some.custom.key") // always returns null, but throws no error
  }
```

Do I have to use something like https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-config ?
Should I use `vertx.getOrCreateContext().config();` or just `config().` ?

**Solution** If it fails to find the config, all returned values will default to null, but not the config itself. For me it was the unit tests only, as they had no config setup.

Comment: If you use `-conf` with a JSON file, the `config()` method of your verticle should give you the content of that file. Can you update your questions with some details about the code? How do you create your fat jar? What's the main class?

Comment: I think it does not work in the `start(Future<Void> fut)` method of the verticle, but then should it not fail, or is some kind of default context taking over ? Can I access the config there ?

Comment: @tsegismont updated with some code

Comment: @tsegismont nulls are actually only there in the unit tests, which was confusing, I still think it should throw errors instead of defaulting to null

Comment: If it's only when running unit tests, then you should check your Maven/IDE configuration.

Comment: @tsegismont The tests are not aware of my config, which makes sense, but failing silently and returning null on config properties is not a good solution, for me if there is no known config the config JsonObject itself should be null (aka NullPointerException), this would help to quickly identify the problem

Comment: This is not the way Vert.x works. In general, we try to use defaults or empty objects rather than failing with NPE.

Comment: @tsegismont IMHO This is more the javascript/web mentality but it makes it hard to debug because it will fail in other parts of the code because the values are null and you have to trace it all the way back to the default magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If VertX fails to find the config, all returned values will default to null, but not the config will not be null and VertX will not raise any errors (silent). For me it was the unit tests only, as they had no config setup, a regular launch was fine with `-conf`.